# Symbol table in linking

Tags: compiler-construction, linker

I read that in two pass linking, during first pass the symbol table of all object codes are combined into a single global table and all segments are stored into segment table with their addresses.

In 2nd pass, symbol resolution takes place by using global symbol table and segment table.

My question is, symbol table only contains value,symbol name and type entries then how does linker come to know the address of each symbol from the global symbol table during symbol resolution in 2nd pass?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When a symbol was defined at assembly time, it was assigned with segment:offset. And if it was declared as PUBLIC, it is stored in global symbol table.

When segments are linked into executable image, each segment obtains its *relative virtual address*. Adding the offset to this segment's RVA gives the value of symbol. Typical public symbol is the entry of library function.

So the answer to your question: offset is specified at assembly time by the compiler, together with segment's name. Segment address is specified at link time by the linker when segments are ordered one after another. Together they yield the desired symbol value (address).

If another object code refers to this public symbol (calls the library function), it is declared as EXTERN and its value is not knowm at assembly time, hence it is temporarily set to zero and accompanied with data structure called *relocation*.
Relocation specifies address of this temporary zero, and name of external symbol. Linker reads the relocation, finds the corresponding public symbol with matching name and then replaces the temporary zero with value of the public symbol.

Comment: Where is this segment:offset pair stored ? I mean in which table ? This link https://www.iecc.com/linker/linker01.html , says global symbol table is just combination of all local symbol tables and not only for public variables .

Comment: Both offset value and segment identification are properties of symbol.

Comment: It is the author of compiler/assembler who decides whethet s/he will keep separate tables for each kind of symbols, or if it's better to maintain one big table and supplement each symbol with a flag specifying its scope (PRIVATE/PUBLIC/EXTERN). In the latter case such table should be called **symbol table** rather than **global symbol table**.

Comment: So, symbol's offset value and it's segment number are stored in symbol table besides the symbol ?

Comment: Yes, beside other symbol properties. Imagine the symbol table as a spreadsheet with one row per symbol and with columns Name, Offset, SegmentId, Type, SourceLineNr, Scope ( PRIVATE/PUBLIC/EXTERN/IMPORT/EXPORT), DLLname ( if imported), etc.